# How to block a sender using Gmail API?

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

In my application I'm currently trying to block a user using a python application via Gmail's API.

Currently I have tried using filter to move the email to spam

`GMAIL.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=m_id,body={ 'addLabelIds': ['SPAM']}).execute()`

But I will still receive future emails from the sender in the inbox.

How do I implement using Gmail API to have future emails from the sender go into the SPAM folder?

(Basically block the sender, like the function in the Gmail web application)

Is this possible, using filters?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation what makes you think something like this is supported in the gmail api?

Answer (score 2):

You have not created a filter for this account, you have just modified the tags on all the emails from that account.

To create a filter you have to use [Method: users.settings.filters.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/create).

You have the example on python [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings#examples):

```
label_id = 'Label_14' # ID of user label to add
filter = {
    'criteria': {
        'from': 'cat-enthusiasts@example.com'
    },
    'action': {
        'addLabelIds': [label_id],
        'removeLabelIds': ['INBOX']
    }
}
result = gmail_service.users().settings().filters().\
    create(userId='me', body=filter).execute()
print 'Created filter: %s' % result.get('id')
```