# I have an idea for blocking spam, I want to know if I can implement it

Tags: gmail-api

I would like to be able to block some of my spammers more effectively, they keep creating different versions of their e-mails so that they can bypass the fact that I have blocked them. I was wondering if there was a way to do something like a SQL code, something to the effect of

BLOCK user WHERE LIKE "%nameofspammer%"

I'm kind of new to coding still so I'm not sure if this is possible but I would like to implement it on one of my spammers so they can no longer bypass the block by renaming their e-mail.

Comment: `bypass the block by renaming their e-mail` - do you have some examples? How would you know 2 different emails are in fact the same person? Zooming out, Captcha/etc. may be a more effective tool - add friction to the spammers' workflow and they may go somewhere else ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION:

Depending on the programming language you're using to code, what you can do is basically create a filter with criteria where you can automatically move the messages from these certain senders' email addresses to. Or you could also move these emails to the spam/thrash folder. You can view these similar samples below for some guidance:

- [How to block a sender using Gmail API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139043/15384825)
- [HOW TO FILTER GMAIL HEADERS & STOP “VIA” SPAM](https://www.geektron.com/2014/01/how-to-filter-gmail-using-email-headers-and-stop-via-spam/#code)

**Gmail API references:**

- [Managing Filters: Matching Criteria](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings#matching_criteria)
- [Action to messages matching the filter criteria](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings#actions)

Comment: If we answered your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.